# How to remove the dots in Wpf Chart which is using Data Visualzation tool kit dll

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-visualization, datavisualization.toolkit

I am working MVVM & Wpf Application, in that I am developing a chart using Data visualization tool kit Chart Line series...

This is my Xaml Code..

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting; assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

    <chartingToolkit:Chart>
         <chartingToolkit:LineSeries
                 DataContext="{Binding}"
                 DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=y}"                 
                 IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=x}" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" >
         </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
         <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="False" Orientation="X" Interval="0">
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="False" Orientation="Y" Interval="0">
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
       </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

I am able to display my chart, but the problem is how to hide dots. (I marked them with pink Circle in the picture (graph/ chart))

[image]

Comment: I got solution from the Following link....

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273268/wpf-charting-how-to-collapse-datapoint-dots-in-lineseries>

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a style with Opacity = 0

```
<Style x:Key="LineDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" ></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
</Style>

<chartingToolkit:LineSeries
    Title="Line"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IndependentValuePath="Int"
    DependentValuePath="LineValue"
    DataPointStyle="{StaticResource LineDataPointStyle}"/>
```